# PayPal Parallel Payments & PhpProBid

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Has anybody had the distinct pleasure of integrating paypal parallel payments into version 6+ of PhpProBid? I'm trying to convert the standard PayPal integration model of: customer buys something --> pays vendor --> vendor pays site fees to make it easier for my sole trader friend - basically he doesn't want to have to worry about chasing up the sites users for payment.

To that end I'm trying to alter the standard PayPal payment system that comes pre-installed as part of the software to support parallel payments with a 70/30% share... I know the files I have to work on, and have tried a number of possible solutions but none seem to work...

Without rattling off a few weeks worth of ideas and coding solutions that ultimately haven't worked i'm not sure where to go.

But in short I have tried altering the 'hidden' variables originally used by the script (which is a completely backwards solution to start with), I've tried implementing someone else code which while the code was brilliant and functional I couldn't work out how to replace the existing script code, and have tried using PayPal's own simple base code samples but for whatever reason even trying to integrate those I suck...

I have many years experience in general web development and integration and can modify most things without much hassle but this has me stumped...

Any advice would be fantastic and can provide code samples or development site access upon request...